# For fights, are you better off with real family members as opposed to hired-guns?

Tags: mafia-wars

Obviously, having actual players in your mafia benefits you because they give you energy packs/gifts/etc.

However, strictly for the purposes of fights, is there any advantage for having actual players in your mafia over the hired-guns that you can buy with reward points?

Comment: oops. With all these new SE sites I got behind on going back and accepting answers. Should be close to 100% now. Thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe there's any appreciable difference between an actual player and a hired gun in fights since they use your weapons and defensive items.

Comment: So their stats for attack and defense don't play into it?